# Возможно ли добавить точку на карту сразу с описанием?

Tags: android

Таким образом я добавляю точку на карту

```
    MarkerOptions myMarkerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

    LatLng myLatLng = new LatLng(49.7762628,73.0950277);
    myMarkerOptions.position(myLatLng);

    mMap.addMarker(myMarkerOptions);
```

а можно ли добавить точку сразу с описанием, как на гугл картах?
[image: пример]

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете написать свой файл JSON в котором будут координаты, название обьекта, время работы , картинки и куча другой информации и просто выводить его, в чем проблемс? У гугла свое АПИ на эту тему

Comment: я хочу использовать то, что есть у гугла. зачем писать свое если уже все места есть у гугла. Если знаете апи которое позволить взять эту инфу поделитесь пожалуйста

Comment: Такие вещи ,думаю , будут в закрытом апи не предназначеном для третьих лиц

Comment: @YerassylTurlygazhy, этот ответ полностью соответствует вашему вопросу. Если вы хотите использовать готовые точки, то это будут именно готовые, не подлежащие изменениею в чистом виде, все готовые точки у вас уже есть на карте и вам нужно их просто найти. Возможно вам подойдёт вот эта ссылка: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/current-place-tutorial, но утите, что большенство функций сейчас у GoogleMaps платные...

Comment: @Valeriy да я хочу использовать готовые точки без изменения. Сейчас изучаю ссылку данную вами, но там пока не нашел как брать идентификаторы мест и добавлять в карту, поделитесь плиз если есть пример кода, где именно сетается место

Comment: @YerassylTurlygazhy, извините за возможнный ввод вас в заблуждение, но я не говорил что там есть решение, а только у точнил что возможно вы найдете что-то там похожее.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, у маркера есть Info Window. Вот пример создания

```
static final LatLng MELBOURNE = new LatLng(-37.81319, 144.96298);
Marker melbourne = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                      .position(MELBOURNE)
                      .title("Melbourne"));
melbourne.showInfoWindow();
```

Больше информации тут https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/infowindows

Comment: выводить хочется не только надпись, а все инфу которую показывает гугл

Comment: Если вы откроете ссылку (которую я скинул выше) вы увидите раздел "Custom info windows", где написано как кастомизировать вид Info Window.